# How do i add bootstrap carousel without click handler?

Tags: react-bootstrap

How can I add carousel without click handler using react-bootstrap

`<Carousel></Carousel>`

Answer (score 0):

When you look into the documentation, you will find out, that a Carousel is working without any click handler per default: https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/components/carousel/#example

Just define Carousel.Items or images directly and you are ready to go: the image will change every every 5 seconds:

```
<Carousel>
  <Carousel.Item>
    <img
      className="d-block w-100"
      src="holder.js/800x400?text=First slide&bg=373940"
      alt="First slide"
    />
    <Carousel.Caption>
      <h3>First slide label</h3>
      <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
    </Carousel.Caption>
  </Carousel.Item>
  <Carousel.Item>
    <img
      className="d-block w-100"
      src="holder.js/800x400?text=Second slide&bg=282c34"
      alt="Second slide"
    />

    <Carousel.Caption>
      <h3>Second slide label</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    </Carousel.Caption>
  </Carousel.Item>
  <Carousel.Item>
    <img
      className="d-block w-100"
      src="holder.js/800x400?text=Third slide&bg=20232a"
      alt="Third slide"
    />

    <Carousel.Caption>
      <h3>Third slide label</h3>
      <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur.</p>
    </Carousel.Caption>
  </Carousel.Item>
</Carousel>
```